# tabular + table results in "Not in outer par mode"

Tags: tables

```
LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10                 \bgroup
```

This is the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{ c c }
            \begin{table}
                \bgroup
                \def\arraystretch{1.2}
                \begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
                    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2} \\
                    & & $a_1$ & $a_2$ \\
                    \hline
                    \multirow{2}{*}{P1} & $a_1$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                    & $a_2$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \egroup
                \caption{Title}
            \end{table}
      & 
      Other text
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You are using the wrong order: table should be around tabular (and use `\centering` instead of center).

Comment: `bgroup` and `egroup` are suoperfuous, `\def\arraystretch{1.2}` should be before `tabular`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect that you like to obtain the following result:

[image]

correct code for above table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}
   \centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
    \begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2}   \\
    &       & $a_1$ & $a_2$             \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{P1}
    & $a_1$ & 0,0   & 0,0               \\
    & $a_2$ & 0,0   & 0,0               \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
&
Other text
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Title}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
from your comments follows, that you like to have two parallel tables:

[image]

for this i suggest to use the `tabularx` table environment for outer table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}
   \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ C C }
    \begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2}   \\
    &       & $a_1$ & $a_2$             \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{P1}
    & $a_1$ & 0,0   & 0,0               \\
    & $a_2$ & 0,0   & 0,0               \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Title of the first table}
    \label{tab:1}
&
    \begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2}   \\
    &       & $a_1$ & $a_2$             \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{P1}
    & $a_1$ & 0,0   & 0,0               \\
    & $a_2$ & 0,0   & 0,0               \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Title of the second table}
    \label{tab:2}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zarko! Actually, I would like to have two tables 1 and 2 (instead of "Other Text") The problem with your answer is that I would get only a single title

Comment: Let's say that I actually want to have two tables/grids side by side each with its own title

Comment: @purpletentacle, what is in the second table?